# Return a boolean value if string matches one of list MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

```
SEQUENCES
-----------------
sequence (blob)


KNOWN_SEQUENCES
-----------------
sequence (blob)
```

I need to return a list of all entries in the sequences table and Id like to return a boolean if it is in the known table list

```
sequence            known
----------------------------------
111423fa686ca          0
066787caf5671          1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See use of 'CASE' in mysql. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html.

I am posting a sample here. Sorry I dont have access to a sql server right now to test this. Try to see if something like this helps.

```
Select s.sequence,
    CASE 
        WHEN (select count(*) from KNOWN_SEQUENCES k where k.sequence = s.sequence) > 0 THEN '1'
        ESLE '0'
    END 
    `known`,
from SEQUENCES s;
```

Also, indexing the table 'KNOWN_SEQUENCES' on column 'sequence' might be better keeping performance in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little long, but it should work.

```
  SELECT
      s.*,
      1 as `known`
    FROM
      sequence AS s
    INNER JOIN
      known_sequences AS ks
    ON
      s.sequence = ks.sequence
UNION
   SELECT
      s.sequence,
      0 AS `known`
   FROM
      sequence AS s
   WHERE
     s.sequence NOT IN
   (
   SELECT
      s2.sequence
    FROM
      sequence AS s2
    LEFT JOIN
      known_sequences AS ks
    ON
      s.sequence == ks.sequence
   )
```

Comment: This is so close. For some reason, results that are known show up twice, once as know and once as not known. The ones that are not know, only show once.

Answer (score 0):

I did get it working, but it takes 3 seconds for only 9,000 records. That may be the best I can do. Luckily I just need to run this once.

```
SELECT
  sequences.*,
  1 as `known`
FROM
  sequences, known_sequences
WHERE sequences.sequence = known_sequences.sequence
UNION
 SELECT
  sequences.*,
  0 as `known`
FROM
  sequences, known_sequences
WHERE sequences.sequence NOT IN(
SELECT known_sequences.sequence
FROM known_sequences) GROUP BY sequences.id
```